# Why is the WPF MenuItem text being trimmed?

Tags: c#, wpf, blend

I've got a View MenuItem which contains a sub-MenuItem Named "Show password".

Why isn't the complete text showing up?

It shows only if I drag the right handle to the right, but I need to understand why can't I see the full text the way it is since it clearly has room to be displayed.
[image]

note: using Blend for VS2013

Comment: When you run your program (F5) rather than in the designer, does all of the text appear or is it truncated there too?

Comment: It shows the same even after compilation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default `WPF MenuItem template` defines a large margin (this is called `Padding` to be precise) between the inner header rectangle and the outer bound.

The empty space to the right edge, as you can see from the screenshot, I believe is for the hovering cursor when user is selecting the menu. You can find this in the menu of most windows applications. The menu item needs to be wide enough (header + reserved space) or the header is truncated.

Setting the Width property to `Auto` (which is the default value) can solve the issue.

Comment: The OP is asking about why the text in the menu item is truncated to "Show pass" instead of "Show password" - he isn't asking about the padding on the left at all.

Comment: The menu width is the default the designer generates, and the reserved space you are mentioning is masking almost half of it.. it doesn't seem normal to me.

Comment: @IneedHelp The default width set by the designer should be "Auto" (I have checked this in Blend), which auto-adjusts according to the length the header. Did you set the Width explicitly?

Comment: @kennyzx I haven't altered the width property, but you're right, setting it to Auto solves the issue. Thank you! I'm accepting your answer, please add the missing bit of info in it.

Comment: @IneedHelp Answer updated according to your feedback.